# How do I get Scala BigDecimal to display a large number of digits?

Tags: scala

Doing the following

```
  val num = BigDecimal(1.0)
  val den = BigDecimal(3.0)
  println((num/den)(MathContext.DECIMAL128))
```

I only get

```
0.3333333333333333333333333333333333
```

Which is less than the 128 I want

Answer (score 5):

The default context is MathContext.DECIMAL128 which is used in all computations so in your example the result of num/den is already rounded to 128 places. You need to set your context on all values first and then do your computations.

```
val mc = new MathContext(512)
val num = BigDecimal(1.0,mc)
val den = BigDecimal(3.0,mc)
println(num/den)
```

Don't try and use MathContext.UNLIMITED unless you know your arithmetic does not produce an unbounded decimal representation. It will blow up even before you try to print.

Answer (score 2):

[MathContext128](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/math/MathContext.html#DECIMAL128) is IEEE 754R Decimal128 format, 34 digits. So the output is correct (I assume the 128 refers to 128 bits of precision, not decimals).

I guess you can make your own MathContext with about four times the precision:

```
MathContext moreContext = new MathContext(512); // 512 bits (!) of precision
```

Comment: This compiles and runs but I'm not getting any more decimal places

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
val mc = new java.math.MathContext(128)
val one_third = (BigDecimal(1, mc) / BigDecimal(3, mc)).toString
// 0. and a bunch of 3

one_third.filter(_ == '3').size // returns 128
```

If you use 512 you'll get 512 '3' digits.